# Multiple Inner Join - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL request but doesn't work...I don't really know why because i'm beginning with SQL...

```
Select CDR.*,
  p1.*,
  p2.*,
  p3.*
From dbo.T_CDR_APPEL CDR
  Inner Join dbo.POS As p1 On CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE = p1.Loc_Code And
    CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'SC%VI%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I%'
  Inner Join dbo.POS As p2 On CDR.CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO = p2.Post_type And
    CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'CCN%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I'
  Inner Join dbo.POS As p3 On CDR.CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO = p3.Backup_Number And
    CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'VoiceMail%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'IF'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do it in steps. Start with the simple 1 table select. If it works as expected, add first join. If it works, add another join etc.

Comment: BTW, `LIKE` without wildcards can usually be replace by `=`.

Comment: It works with the first Inner Join...but then with the second one does'nt work

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Seems like you have no matching data. With the second join, start with first condition only, test, add second condition etc,

Comment: You're right ! no data with the 2nd request

Comment: You have to ask yourself what the expected result is now...

Comment: It would help, if you told us what the query is supposed to do. (And next time please don't say "but doesn't work", but explain what happens, for "but doesn't work" can mean many things, like too many records, too few, an exception, ...) Maybe you want to change the inner joins to outer joins? It seems you are looking for p1 records provided CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I%' only for instance.

Comment: The query is supposed to send me a table with a join but i depends on Type of the table CDR

If type = 'I' the join have to be on Last Redir number of Table CDR and Post_Code of Table POS
If type = 'IF' the join have to be on Last Redir number of Table CDR and Backup_Number of Table POS
If type Like 'I%' And Loc_Code Like 'SC%VI%' the join have to be on Loc_Code of Table CDR and Loc_Code of Table POS

Don't know if it is understable

Comment: An inner join always requires to find matching records and when there is no match the main record doesn't appear in the results. Change your joins from `inner join` to `left outer join` to keep the CDR record whether there is a match or not.

Comment: Doesn't work also with left outer join...

Comment: I think it's time you tag your DBMS (Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL? ...) and also tell us what tool you are using to execute the query (SQL Developer, PhpMyAdmin, a PHP program written by yourself, ...).

Comment: It's SQL Server and the tool is a french BI tool (maybe SQL Developer but note sure...have to ask to the company )

Comment: I've added SQL Server to the tags for you. "Doesn't work also with left outer join" again says nothing. What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Or does the query run but returns no rows? I suggest you remove ".*, p1.*, p2.*, p3.*` from your select list for a start. You can add them later
again. Then start with only `From dbo.T_CDR_APPEL CDR`. Then add `LEFT JOIN dbo.POS As p1 On ...`, then p2, then p3.

Comment: The problem is that with this software it doesn't return me the error...

Comment: With only `From dbo.T_CDR_APPEL CDR` the request is running but never send me results

Answer (score 2):

Your select statement

```
Select CDR.*,
  p1.*,
  p2.*,
  p3.*
From dbo.T_CDR_APPEL CDR
  Inner Join dbo.POS As p1 On CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE = p1.Loc_Code And
    CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'SC%VI%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I%'
  Inner Join dbo.POS As p2 On CDR.CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO = p2.Post_type And
    CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'CCN%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'I'
  Inner Join dbo.POS As p3 On CDR.CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO = p3.Backup_Number And
    CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE Like 'VoiceMail%' And CDR.CDR_TYPE Like 'IF'
```

is basically the same as

```
SELECT CDR.*,
  p1.*,
  p2.*,
  p3.*
FROM dbo.T_CDR_APPEL CDR
  INNER JOIN dbo.POS AS p1 ON CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE = p1.Loc_Code
  INNER JOIN dbo.POS AS p2 ON CDR.CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO = p2.Post_type
  INNER JOIN dbo.POS AS p3 ON CDR.CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO = p3.Backup_Number
WHERE
    CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE LIKE 'SC%VI%' AND     
    CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE LIKE 'CCN%' AND 
    CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE LIKE 'VoiceMail%' AND 
    CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I%' AND 
    CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I' AND 
    CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'IF'
```

So, the problem is the `WHERE` clause with many combination of `AND` conditions for the same columns `CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE` and `CDR.CDR_TYPE`. Try replacing `AND` with `OR` instead.

**Update**:
Since `p1,p2,p3` are of the same Table, to avoid duplicate columns, try this

```
SELECT CDR.*, p.* FROM 
(
   SELECT *, 
   (CASE 
        WHEN CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I%' THEN CDR_LOC_CODE
        WHEN CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I' THEN CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO
        WHEN CDR_TYPE LIKE 'IF' THEN CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO
        ELSE ''
    END) TMP_COL FROM dbo.T_CDR_APPEL 
) CDR
INNER JOIN dbo.POS p ON
   (CASE 
        WHEN CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I%' THEN p.Loc_Code
        WHEN CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I' THEN p.Post_type
        WHEN CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'IF' THEN p.Backup_Number
        ELSE ''
    END) = CDR.TMP_COL
WHERE
   (CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE LIKE 'SC%VI%' AND CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I%') OR
   (CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE LIKE 'CCN%' AND CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I') OR
   (CDR.CDR_LOC_CODE LIKE 'VoiceMail%' AND CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'IF')
```

Note: Running the query above might take a while with large tables. You may want to add some conditions to the `WHERE` clause for further tuning. Also we should put the `WHERE` clause to the sub query since `CDR_LOC_CODE` and `CDR_TYPE` are of the same table `dbo.T_CDR_APPEL`. Also check Null or empty for the dynamic column `TMP_COL` in order to avoid joining tables `ON '' = ''` or `ON NULL = NULL`.

```
SELECT CDR.*, p.* FROM 
(
   SELECT *, 
   (CASE 
        WHEN CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I%' THEN CDR_LOC_CODE
        WHEN CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I' THEN CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO
        WHEN CDR_TYPE LIKE 'IF' THEN CDR_LAST_REDIR_NO
        ELSE ''
    END) TMP_COL FROM dbo.T_CDR_APPEL 
    WHERE
       (CDR_LOC_CODE LIKE 'SC%VI%' AND CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I%') OR
       (CDR_LOC_CODE LIKE 'CCN%' AND CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I') OR
       (CDR_LOC_CODE LIKE 'VoiceMail%' AND CDR_TYPE LIKE 'IF')
) CDR
INNER JOIN dbo.POS p ON
   (CASE 
        WHEN CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I%' THEN p.Loc_Code
        WHEN CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'I' THEN p.Post_type
        WHEN CDR.CDR_TYPE LIKE 'IF' THEN p.Backup_Number
        ELSE ''
    END) = CDR.TMP_COL AND NULLIF(CDR.TMP_COL, '') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: An error prevents the query from working:
The "" data source produced the following error:

The data source has the duplicate column names (Loc_Code)

Comment: Well spotted. Putting these conditions in the ON clauses would only make sense for outer joins, and I have an inkling that is what the OP is reallly after.

Comment: The queries look fine. How do you execute them? It seems your programm complains about Loc_Code being multiple times in the results (once for CDR, once for p1, p2, and p3 each). That shouldn't be a problem usually, but maybe your program is not capable of handling this. You can use aliases to circumvent this: `select cdr.loc_code as cdr_loc_code, p1.loc_code as p1_loc_code, ...`.

Comment: I'll try this in 2 min

Comment: @ThorstenKettner +1 for the hint using aliases.

Comment: In fact CDR and p1,p2,p3 all contain the colomn Loc_Code is it a problem ?

Comment: With the case code, error at p1.* -> unexpected token ".*" at line 2,pos 45

Comment: The `CASE` construct is invalid. `CASE` results in one value, but p1.* etc. is more than one value.

Comment: I think you should list some fields you need, do not `SELECT *`

Comment: The request is running but no end...seems like running but nothing happening

Comment: @Alexandre Uh! my bad, joining using `ON 1 = 1` which causes running the query indefinity. See the update again. :D

Comment: @Alexandre did you replace `ELSE ''` with `ELSE 'XXX'` and `ELSE 'YYY'` respectively?